# laravel-echo-server on laradock ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 with private channel

Tags: vue.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo, laradock

I use redis on laradock, and passport to authenticated channel. if i use public channel, socket is connected, but if i modify channel event in **NewMessage.php** to private, i get error `Error sending authentication request` when trying to authenticate . anyone have same problem? how to resolve it?

**laravel-echo-server.json** configuration:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://platform.lenna.test/app/public",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

this is my laravel event **NewMessage.php**

```
...
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $app;
    public $room;
    public function __construct(Message $message, Room $room, App $app)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->room = $room;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('ChannelApp.' . $this->app->id);
    }
}
```

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**Channel.php** routes

```
Broadcast::channel('ChannelApp.{appId}', function ($user, $appId) {
    return true;
})
```

This is my laravel-echo-server error logs:

[image]

Comment: Please post error logs and code as text and not as an image! This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @thmspl i've improve my question

Comment: As you can read (by your self!) in the error message you are trying to connec to the host `127.0.0.1` with port `80` and he's not answering your request. So this can have 1000 reasons and to debug this you need to post every related code you have. It should be clear that nobody can help you with such a common error message and so little code you've posted! First check that the metnioned host and port is correct. Then check every log file if there are more informations.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, What i discovered was the laravel-echo-server resolves the "http://platform.lenna.test" to 127.0.0.1.

So what I did was added the "nginx docker ip   platform.lenna.test" to the /etc/hosts of laravel-echo-server and that worked for me.